# How to save a numpy array with some specific elements of all samples provided by a generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, generator

Let's assume I have a generator yielding a tuple x,y.
I would like to save only all x elements which are yield from this generator.
But, I want to use .npy files to do so.

I know that if my generator only yields one element per iteration, let's say z, I can use the following code to save this element in a numpy array file.

```
numpy.save('array.npy', numpy.stack(generator))
```

But, well, I have no idea how to modify this line to solve my problem. I mean, I don't think it is possible to use this.

Please could you help me ? I would really appreciate any helps :)
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generator:

```
In [406]: g = ((i,i+10) for i in range(5))
```

An array from that:

```
In [407]: arr = np.stack(g)                                                              
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3242: 
FutureWarning: arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" 
type such as list or tuple. Support for non-sequence iterables 
such as generators is deprecated as of NumPy 1.16 and will raise 
an error in the future.
    if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
In [408]: arr                                                                            
Out[408]: 
array([[ 0, 10],
       [ 1, 11],
       [ 2, 12],
       [ 3, 13],
       [ 4, 14]])
```

the first column:

```
In [409]: arr[:,0]                                                                       
Out[409]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Or use `fromiter` with a compound dtype to make a structured array:

```
In [410]: g = ((i,i+10) for i in range(5))                                               
In [411]: arr = np.fromiter(g, 'i,i')                                                    
In [412]: arr                                                                            
Out[412]: 
array([(0, 10), (1, 11), (2, 12), (3, 13), (4, 14)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
In [413]: arr['f0']                                                                      
Out[413]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32)
```

Avoid the warning by making a list from the generator:

```
In [414]: g = ((i,i+10) for i in range(5))                                               
In [415]: np.array(list(g))                                                              
Out[415]: 
array([[ 0, 10],
       [ 1, 11],
       [ 2, 12],
       [ 3, 13],
       [ 4, 14]])
```

Sooner of later you have to 'instantiate' the generator.  Generators only save memory when several are chained.  A numpy array stores all values, not the generator or its 'potential' values.  So generators aren't that useful when the final target is an array.

Comment: Yes, I did some experiments, and you right : it is not that useful to use generator. I wanted to write all (x,y) generated into two files to avoid using so much memory but while looking at my memory : it is not working. Hopefully, I can run my code but, well, it is somewhat frustrating... Thank you for your answer ! You greatly answered :)